# Switching a elements in char array to the corresponding positions in an int array java

Tags: java, arrays, char, int

I'm trying to switch the elements in the letters array to the corresponding positions in the positions array. The elements are getting swapped but not to the right position. Am I doing this completely wrong or is there just a problem in my logic?

```
public class Words
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        char letters[] = {'l', 'o', 'e', 'h', 'l'};
        int positions[] = {2, 4, 1, 0, 3};

        int limit1 = letters.length;
        int temp1;
        char temp2;
        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
        {
            limit1--;
            for(int j = 0; j < limit1; j++)
            {
                temp1 = positions[j];
                temp2 = letters[temp1];
                letters[temp1] = letters[j];
                letters[j] = temp2;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(letters[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `temp2 = letters[temp1]` means that you're assigning e.g. `'l'` to `temp2`, and the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) / Unicode value of an `l` is **`108`**. You're then doing `letters[temp2]`, i.e. `letters[108]`, but `letters` is only 5 long, so you get exception. --- Looking at the code inside the `j` loop, I'm baffled as to what you're even trying to do. Use `temp` variable makes it look like you were trying a *swap*, but there is certainly no swapping going on.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to swap, thanks for helping me realize id assigned temp2 as an int instead of a char. I now see that my final condition in the loop is wrong as well.

Comment: im going to edit the code to show you what it has been changed to

Comment: Once you have swapped a pair of letters, the `positions` array will be out of sync with the `letters` array. --- Are you *required* to do this in-place? Because it would be so much easier if you could just create a new array for the result. --- Also, re-think your logic. This can be done using a single loop. Nested loops are not needed.

Comment: oh ok, so I create a separate array and assign it the letters in the required positions, no need to change the given arrays. That makes sense to me

Comment: just solved it, thank you for your help. I've been looking at this too long and was overthinking it. I wish i could give you the answer but ill post what my final code was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to do this in-place, it would be a lot easier to just create a new array.

```
char[] letters = {'l', 'o', 'e', 'h', 'l'};
int[] positions = {2, 4, 1, 0, 3};

char[] result = new char[letters.length];
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
    result[positions[i]] = letters[i];

System.out.println(result);
```

*Output*

```
hello
```

---

For an in-place solution, the following will do. Same output as above.

```
char letters[] = {'l', 'o', 'e', 'h', 'l'};
int positions[] = {2, 4, 1, 0, 3};

for (int i = 0, j; i < letters.length; i++) {
    while ((j = positions[i]) != i) {
        char tempLetter = letters[i];
        letters[i] = letters[j];
        letters[j] = tempLetter;
        int tempPosition = positions[i];
        positions[i] = positions[j];
        positions[j] = tempPosition;
    }
}

System.out.println(letters);
```

That can easily be written using only one loop.

```
for (int i = 0, j; i < letters.length; ) {
    if ((j = positions[i]) == i) {
        i++;
    } else {
        char tempLetter = letters[i];
        letters[i] = letters[j];
        letters[j] = tempLetter;
        int tempPosition = positions[i];
        positions[i] = positions[j];
        positions[j] = tempPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think that this solution is too obvious and simple  and that the real challenge is to do it in place.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong:

```
 ...
 temp2 = letters[temp1]; // temp2 is a letter now 
 ...
 letters[temp2] = letters[j]; // the index you are using is a unicode char
```

Comment: yeah, I edited the code as I didn't catch that. I assigned temp 2 as a char instead and changed a line of code in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Question solved, there is an easier way where you create an array and assign it the elements at the position given. This is a much easier way, idea given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas

```
public class Words
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        char letters[] = {'l', 'o', 'e', 'h', 'l'};
        int positions[] = {2, 4, 1, 0, 3};

        char[] array = new char [letters.length];
        int limit1 = letters.length;
        int temp1;
        char temp2;

        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
        {
            temp2 = letters[i];
            temp1 = positions[i];
            array[temp1] = temp2;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```